# **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Tags: python, mysql, tunneling

I wanted to use an ssh tunnel to access a Mysql database.
Unfortunately the architecture of this code doesn't seem to support the format of my query, as the function doesn't seem to be compatible with the format of my query.

```
/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/MySqlLocalhostTest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:236: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 96, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 65, in run_query
  File "/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/MySqlLocalhostTest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 399, in read_sql_query
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "/Users/peter/PycharmProjects/MySqlLocalhostTest/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 2081, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

simple statements like (Select * From Table) work perfectly.

What would I have to change either in the mysql syntax or the function to make this work?

sorry for being a noob. I would appreciate any advice or help.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import logging
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder


ssh_host = '172.xxx.xxx.xxx'
ssh_username = 'root'
ssh_password = 'xxxxxxx'
database_username = 'root'
database_password = 'xxxxxxxx'
database_name = 'analysis-db'
localhost = '127.0.0.1'


def open_ssh_tunnel(verbose=False):
    """Open an SSH tunnel and connect using a username and password.

    :param verbose: Set to True to show logging
    :return tunnel: Global SSH tunnel connection
    """

    if verbose:
        sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG

    global tunnel
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, 22),
        ssh_username=ssh_username,
        ssh_password=ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
    )

    tunnel.start()


def mysql_connect():
    """Connect to a MySQL server using the SSH tunnel connection

    :return connection: Global MySQL database connection
    """

    global connection

    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        user=database_username,
        passwd=database_password,
        db=database_name,
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port
    )


def run_query(sql):
    """Runs a given SQL query via the global database connection.

    :param sql: MySQL query
    :return: Pandas dataframe containing results
    """

    return pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)


def mysql_disconnect():
    """Closes the MySQL database connection.
    """

    connection.close()


def close_ssh_tunnel():
    """Closes the SSH tunnel connection.
    """

    tunnel.close

day_of_test = "24.01.22"
gold_close = 1000
sap_close= 1000
bonds_close= 1000
btc_est= 1000
btc_actual= 1000
actual_difference = 1000

open_ssh_tunnel()
mysql_connect()

query = ("INSERT INTO `ML1`(`day_of_test`, `gold_close`, `sap_close`, `bonds_close`, `btc_est`, `btc_actual`,`actual_difference`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"%
        (day_of_test, gold_close, sap_close, bonds_close, btc_est, btc_actual, actual_difference))

df = run_query(query)
      

print(df)
df.head()
mysql_disconnect()
close_ssh_tunnel()
```

Comment: in your ```df = run_query(...)``` line,  replace ```, %s);",``` with ```, %s);" %```

Comment: With the previous comment's change, what error do you have?  Please include that error in your post.

Comment: I added the % instead of the syntax.
The error code changed to;
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `df = run_query(...)` line.

You used a comma; but you should use a %.

i.e.

```
df = run_query("INSERT INTO `ML1`(`day_of_test`, `gold_close`, `sap_close`, `bonds_close`, `btc_est`, `btc_actual`,`actual_difference`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);" %
        (day_of_test, gold_close, sap_close, bonds_close, btc_est, btc_actual, actual_difference))
```

Comment: unfortunately that returns 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: The answer as posted is valid for your initial problem.   Your "NoneType" object is not iterable problem is a different matter.